# How to create a collecting socket relay with socat?

Tags: ubuntu, socket, socat

I'm using `socat` to forward to another port on localhost:

`socat tcp-l:5050,fork,reuseaddr tcp:localhost:2020`

Problem: if the program running on `2020` is down, socat will answer incoming connections like:

`socat[435965] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:2020, 16): Connection refused`

Question: can I make socat collect incoming messages, putting them on hold until the target port becomes alive again (at least within a timeout of eg some minutes)?

What I'm looking for is: socat should pretend to clients that the port `5050` is still alive, and the connection should just hang until application on port `2020` comes alive and accept the socket request from waiting 5050.